# Content area takes 100% screen width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to replicate the basic structure of the page which is base on theme https://themes.muffingroup.com/be/restaurant5/.

I tried to use bootstrap row & columns that seems to have created its own problem and when try to do it with Bootstrap using custom css it doesnt work as the theme.

In current case main content takes 100% and side menu is about 250px, since side nav has fixed position main content area has 100 % with of the screen, i want main content are to take on remain space Content Area - Side Nav

I can use `.side-content {width:calc(100% - 250px) !important}`  but i am curious how they are doing the sample theme as i could not see using calc function

https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/oNXdgWz

```css
body{font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
.side-content{background-color:red; withd:100%; float:left;
 max-width: 100% !important;
 width: 100% !important;
 margin: 0 !important;
 overflow:hidden;
 background-color: #ccc;
}
.side-nav {
 text-align:center;
 background-color: #FCFCFC;
 position: fixed;
 width: 250px;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 right:0;
 z-index: 9002;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 0 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
 box-shadow: 2px 0 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.15);

}
.img-logo {
 margin-top:50px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 max-height: 100%;
 width:100%;
 max-width:150px;
}
.nav-menu{ 
list-style: none outside;
padding-top:30px;
margin-top:30px;
padding-left:0px;
}
.nav-menu > li {
 
 margin: 0;
 z-index: 203;
 display: block;
 float: left;
  width: 100%;
 float: none;
 position: relative;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:600;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 padding:5px 15px;
}

.main-c{ background:yellow;}

.sone{position:relative;width:100%; height:100%; background:blue;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="assets/css/main.css">
    <title>Page Title HERE!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <nav class="side-nav">
   <img class="img-logo" src="https://themes.muffingroup.com/be/restaurant5/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/restaurant5.png"/>
   <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Abouts Us</li>
    <li>Our Menu</li>
    <li>Special Offers</li>
    <li>Testimonials</li>
    <li>Gallery</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="side-content">
   <div class="sone"> SECTION ONE
   <p> this is intro area </p></div>
   <div class="stwo">SECTION TWO - About us </div>
   <div class="sthree">SECTION THREE - Our menu</div>
  </div>

   
 
 
 
 
 
 

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Leaning In your reference theme, They are using padding-right: 250px!important; on body. So there is no need to use any calc function.

Comment: That what i was looking for i checked almost every tag except body tag..

Comment: I am happy, I could help you.